# Is the usage of reside for non-living objects correct?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Is the following usage of reside correct?
"If we deform a sphere to points, those points must be in a region where the sphere used to reside."

Comment: This is not really an English language question, rather what's conventional use of the word *reside* in a particular field.

Comment: This is certainly a valid English language question. But you need to show evidence of reasonable research on ELU. What does [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/reside) say seem to imply?

Answer (score 2):

It's not easy to find the 'be located' sense of 'reside'. It's given on [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reside), but there, the computing domain is specified. However, I have seen this sense used outside the computing field, and would consider such usage a little unusual (hinting at anthropomorphism)
 rather than wrong.

> **reside**  intr.v. ...
>
> 4. Computers To be located or stored: a file that resides on a shared drive.

[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reside) makes things crystal clear:

> **reside** verb
>
> 1 no object, with adverbial of place
>
> Have one's permanent home in a particular place. ‘people who work in
>   the city actually reside in neighbouring towns’
>
> 1.1 Be situated. ‘the paintings now reside on the walls of a restaurant’